# AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'z'

Tags: python

I want to plot a 3D plot using seaborn and I have the following code

```
tsne_doc = pd.DataFrame()
tsne_doc['tsne-3d-one'] = tsne_results_doc[:,0]
tsne_doc['tsne-3d-two'] = tsne_results_doc[:,1]
tsne_doc['tsne-3d-three'] = tsne_results_doc[:,2]
```

Then I did my plotting using the following code

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
sns.scatterplot(
    x="tsne-3d-one", y="tsne-3d-two", z='tsne-3d-three',
    data=tsne_doc,
    legend="full",
    alpha=0.3
)
plt.show()
```

And then I am getting the following error.

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Kirchoff\Desktop\segmentation.ipynb Cell 14' in <cell line: 3>()
      1 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
      2 ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
----> 3 sns.scatterplot(
      4     x="tsne-3d-one", y="tsne-3d-two", z="tsne-3d-three",
      5     data=tsne_doc,
      6     legend="full",
      7     alpha=0.3
      8 )
      9 plt.show()
```

Here we go

```
File c:\Users\Kirchoff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py:46, in _deprecate_positional_args.<locals>.inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     36     warnings.warn(
     37         "Pass the following variable{} as {}keyword arg{}: {}. "
     38         "From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument "
   (...)
     43         FutureWarning
44     )
     45 kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46 return f(**kwargs)
```

Error code

```
File c:\Users\Kirchoff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py:827, in scatterplot(x, y, hue, style, size, data, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, markers, style_order, x_bins, y_bins, units, estimator, ci, n_boot, alpha, x_jitter, y_jitter, legend, ax, **kwargs)
    823     return ax
    825 p._attach(ax)
--> 827 p.plot(ax, kwargs)
    829 return ax
```

Error Code

```
File c:\Users\Kirchoff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py:608, in _ScatterPlotter.plot(self, ax, kws)
    603 scout_size = max(
    604     np.atleast_1d(kws.get("s", [])).shape[0],
    605     np.atleast_1d(kws.get("c", [])).shape[0],
    606 )
    607 scout_x = scout_y = np.full(scout_size, np.nan)
--> 608 scout = ax.scatter(scout_x, scout_y, **kws)
    609 s = kws.pop("s", scout.get_sizes())
    610 c = kws.pop("c", scout.get_facecolors())
```

Error code

```
File c:\Users\Kirchoff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1412, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1409 @functools.wraps(func)
   1410 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1411     if data is None:
-> 1412         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1414     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1415     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1416                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))
```

Continuation of the error

```
File c:\Users\Kirchoff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py:2389, in Axes3D.scatter(self, xs, ys, zs, zdir, s, c, depthshade,
*args, **kwargs)
   2386 if np.may_share_memory(zs_orig, zs):  # Avoid unnecessary copies.
   2387     zs = zs.copy()
-> 2389 patches = super().scatter(xs, ys, s=s, c=c, *args, **kwargs)
   2390 art3d.patch_collection_2d_to_3d(patches, zs=zs, zdir=zdir,
   2391                                 depthshade=depthshade)
   2393 if self._zmargin < 0.05 and xs.size > 0:
```

The error continue

```
File c:\Users\Kirchoff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1412, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1409 @functools.wraps(func)
   1410 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1411     if data is None:
-> 1412         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1414     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1415     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1416                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))
```

Continuation of the error

```
File c:\Users\Kirchoff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:4468, in Axes.scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4458 collection = mcoll.PathCollection(
   4459         (path,), scales,
   4460         facecolors=colors,
   (...)
   4465         alpha=alpha
   4466         )
   4467 collection.set_transform(mtransforms.IdentityTransform())
-> 4468 collection.update(kwargs)
   4470 if colors is None:
   4471     collection.set_array(c)
```

The error continues as follows

```
File c:\Users\Kirchoff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py:1064, in Artist.update(self, props)
   1062             func = getattr(self, f"set_{k}", None)
1063             if not callable(func):
-> 1064                 raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object "
   1065                                      f"has no property {k!r}")
   1066             ret.append(func(v))
   1067 if ret:

AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'z'
```

Where am I getting it wrong??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [mre] and make it possible for others to reproduce the problem. Is this code using `seaborn` and `matplotlib`? If so, those are also useful tags for the question. I'm not clear on what it has to do with `machine-learning`, though.

Comment: Seaborn doesn't do 3D plots

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Ok so if I want to do 3D plots I have to just go with matplotlib right?

Comment: Ok @John Gordon let me update it

Answer (score 0):

**sns.scatterplot() doesn't support 3D plots**

[image: Parameters for seaborn scatterplot]

Link to seaborn documentation:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html

**I recommend using MATLAB Meshgrid for visualisation of 3D plots**

Example:

```
x = 0:2:6;
y = 0:1:6;
z = 0:3:6;
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
F = X.^2 + Y.^2 + Z.^2;
```

Link to MATLAB meshgrid documentation:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html